# Windows Dynamic Disk not reading in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, disk, partitioning, drive, disk-management

While using windows i changed my hard disk partitions from "Logical Disk" to "Dynamic Disk"..... then i installed Ubuntu in c drive. when i opened ubuntu the contents of C:Drive are shown but i am unable to view the contents of D drive or e drive (both of them are dynamic). Please help.. i tried reinstalling ubuntu quite a number of times which didn't help. Also The windows disk partition manager is unable to change the drives back to Logical Drive.. What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

"Dynamic Disks" are a Windows proprietary format that can not be used on other operating systems like Ubuntu.  You need to convert it back to a basic disk in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk. You can do this either through the Windows interface, or using the command-line.

## Using the Windows interface

1. Back up all volumes on the disk you want to convert from dynamic to basic.
2. Open Computer Management (Local).
3. In the console tree, click Computer Management (Local), click Storage, and then click Disk Management.
4. Right-click each volume on the dynamic disk you want to convert to a basic disk, and then click Delete Volume for each volume on the disk.
5. When all volumes on the disk have been deleted, right-click the disk, and then click Convert To Basic Disk.

## Using a command line

Back up all volumes on the disk you want to convert from dynamic to basic.
For more information about backing up volumes, see Related Topics.

Open Command Prompt.

Type:

```
diskpart
```

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

```
list disk
```

Make note of the dynamic disk you want to convert to a basic disk.

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

```
select diskn
```

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

```
detail diskn
```

For each volume on the disk, at the DISKPART prompt, type:

```
select volume=n
```

and then type:

```
delete volume
```

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

```
select diskn
```

Specify the disk number of the disk that you want to convert to a basic disk.

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

```
convert basic
```