# How do I correctly partition for a dual-boot 12.04 install?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I tried to partition and install Ubuntu 12.04 a week ago and got very far. I shrunk my Windows partition and formatted it for a fresh Ubuntu install to dual-boot alongside Win7. I got so far as the partition screen in Ubuntu and had no idea what I was doing at that point. I screwed around a bit and almost got through the installation until I received [this error](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v294/AmericanErrorst/Tech/IMG_20140113_194836349_HDR_zpsf53cec0c.jpg):

[image: message box during installation, about how GRUB could not install]

The title of the message was:

> Unable to install GRUB to /dev/dm-1

And the contents of the message were:

> Executing 'grub-install /dev/dm-1' failed.
>
> This is a fatal error.

I can't afford to screw up my Windows as I don't have another computer and have virtually no time to fix the mistakes except on the weekends.

I know that there are a ton of posts on this but unfortunately, I have no idea what "swap partitions" or anything are. I'm literally brand new but don't want to start over from scratch. Is there any way I can do this safely without harming my existing windows partition?

---

When I boot from the USB installer I created it doesn't give me the option to install alongside. Is this because I am not using the .iso and booting from that? If I could avoid the manual partitioning and let Ubuntu do it, I would gladly do so.

Answer (score 1):

#### The extra partiton Ubuntu *can't use* may be preventing it from automatically partitioning.

You said "I shrunk my Windows partition and formatted it for a fresh Ubuntu install to dual-boot alongside Win7."

If you're able to shrink the Windows partition and you make sure to shut down or reboot Windows normally before attempting to install Ubuntu (that is, do *not* have Windows just hibernated when you boot the installer), Ubuntu should be able to make its own partitions. You said you shrunk down the Windows partition. I'm guessing you did this in the Disk Management utility in Windows or some other utility you're comfortable using (since you said you don't really know how to use the manual partitioning utility that's part of the Ubuntu installer).

But it sounds from what you said that you *created a partition yourself* for Ubuntu to use. Ubuntu will not automatically use this (and probably cannot, as NTFS is not supported and by default Ubuntu makes *two* partitions for itself).

Therefore, the best thing to do--especially since your preference is for Ubuntu to partition itself, and that appears most in line with your needs--is to *remove the empty partition you made for Ubuntu to use*. I believe the odd error installing GRUB is probably the result of incorrect manual partitioning. If that is the case, it should go away if you can get Ubuntu to make its own partitions.

After removing the partition you recently created, try booting the Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB and attempting installation again. If there's free *unpartitioned* space on the disk large enough for Ubuntu to be installed comfortably, then Ubuntu's installer won't try to resize partitions, and it should just work.

...Unless your whole disk is formatted as [a Windows dynamic disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager#Basic_volumes_and_dynamic_volumes). Ubuntu cannot install to such a disk. In that case you'd have [to convert it back to a "basic disk"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90643/dynamic-disk-not-reading) (or install to a different physical drive). You probably are not--Windows does not make your disk "dynamic" unless you tell it to--but it is possible.

Related information:

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
- [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)
- [Install Alongside Windows or Something Else - Which should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223341/install-alongside-windows-or-something-else-which-should-i-use)
- [The official installation instructions.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)
- ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else)

---

#### Shrink down the Windows partition manually in Windows, or leave it for Ubuntu's installer?

You [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408317/how-do-i-correctly-partition-for-a-dual-boot-12-04-install/408334?noredirect=1#comment525061_408334):

> I did everything exactly as you guessed/described. I have since rejoined that partition back to my Windows partition. Just for final clarity, you are telling me NOT to partition anything at all from my current, existing windows C: partition and to just run Ubuntu from the USB/CD and it should be able to create its own?

Ubuntu's installer *should* be able to resize your Windows partition, but sometimes it is not able to do so (even if you are not currently hibernated in Windows). Since you are able and willing to repartition in Windows, I think it *does* make sense to create space for Ubuntu in Windows's Disk Management utility.

However, this space should be *unpartitioned*. That is, it should not be a new additional partition, **just empty space on the disk with *no partition in it***. This is the result of shrinking down the Windows partition without making a new one (or alternatively, of deleting the new one but not expanding the Windows partition).

Comment: I did everything exactly as you guessed/described. I have since rejoined that partition back to my Windows partition. Just for final clarity, you are telling me NOT to partition anything at all from my current, existing windows C: partition and to just run Ubuntu from the USB/CD and it should be able to create its own?

Comment: And thank you SO MUCH for your help. Not only efficient and knowledgeable but also timely and understanding. When I can upvote, I will.

Comment: @zkrocek You shouldn't make an NTFS partition (or any partition) for Ubuntu in Disk Management, as Ubuntu can't install to such a partition. If you leave *unpartitioned space on disk*, that may save Ubuntu from having to repartition. But Ubuntu should be able to shrink your Windows partition itself, if necessary. I've expanded my answer to address yoru question fully. (I'm glad to have helped. We'll see how much it actually helps, if at all, once you try installing Ubuntu. It is *possible*, after all, that something else is preventing GRUB from installing properly. One step at a time...)

Comment: It looks like that didn't work. Although I DID have the option to install alongside the current operating system, I still received the above pictured error. Now, Windows boots up all funky and takes a very long time. When it does login to win7, my explorer windows are blinky and it's not functioning properly.

Comment: Also, it did use the 50GB unpartitioned free space and made 2 partitions with it for itself. Alas, grub still not working. :(

Comment: I keep trying new things to no avail. I re-joined the unpartitioned space back to the C: partition and now it will not give me the option to install alongside Windows. I am currently running Ubuntu off of the usb stick, but have not been able to install it yet.

Comment: One last comment before I go to bed and leave this for tomorrow: I am using a USB Key Installer, if that makes any difference during the installation. Today I reformatted the key with a fresh download of 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Would it just be easier to buy a second hard drive and install it to its own HDD?