# Can Ubuntu read dynamic disk?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, disk, drive, disk-management

Due a mistake while installing Lubuntu, I converted my Windows Basic Disk to Dynamic Disk(I found this by using disklart from command prompt using Windows Recovery Tools). Now Windows cannot read my drive. But I CAN mount the drive in Lubuntu 18.04 Live USB. [But I had read on the internet that Ubuntu cannot read Dynamic Disk.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90643/windows-dynamic-disk-not-reading-in-ubuntu#:%7E:text=%22Dynamic%20Disks%22%20are%20a%20Windows,a%20basic%20disk%20in%20Windows.) Why am I able to do this?

Comment: The question you linked to is very old. Things change over time, so it may no longer be true.

Comment: @popey Yes. Probably right.

Comment: I would suggest you provide details of what Lubuntu you're talking about to, ie. is it *legacy* lubuntu or a release using LXDE (thus uses `gparted` & like GTK tools) or a *modern* lubuntu using LXQt (and thus KDE Partition Manager instead). I can't help with your question sorry, but I don't even know what disk management tools you are talking about with Lubuntu as you haven't specified a release.

Comment: @guiverc Lubuntu 18.04

Comment: Still best to use Windows tools, LDM is older rarely used with gpt partitioning as there is no more 4 primary partition limit with gpt. You may now be able to see dynamic partitions from Linux:
`sudo apt-get install ldmtool`